# Using same integers multiple times in scanf

Tags: c, scanf

is it possible to use same integers in multiple scanf's? For example, I input int i and j, then give them a value in scanf, and print their sum. Then use another scanf to assign different values to the same integers, and now add THEIR sum..

Comment: How else would you be able to read data in a loop? Did you understand the idea of variables?

Comment: You can assign to a non-const object multiple times within its lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
int a, b;
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
printf("%d\n", a + b);

scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
printf("%d\n", a + b);
```

Of course it would work. The variable's value simply changes. Its the same if you wrote

```
int a;

a = 4;
. . .
a = 8
```